# Using AVCaptureDevice as SCNScene background content

Tags: ios, avfoundation, scenekit

During the [SceneKit: What's New presentation at WWCD2017](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/604/?time=2649) (44:19) it was stated that we can now use `AVCaptureDevice` as background content for `SCNScene`.

Snippet from the presentation:

```
let captureDevice: AVCaptureDevice = ...
scene.background.contents = captureDevice
```

However the following code

```
let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back)!
scene.background.contents = captureDevice
```

produces an error:

```
[SceneKit] Error: Cannot get pixel buffer (CVPixelBufferRef)
```

I also tried to create and start `AVCaptureSession` and then use the device, but it gives the same result.

What might be an issue here?

Comment: Please note that the bug seems to be fixed in iOS 11.2—I edited my original answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**

This bug seems to be fixed in iOS 11.2

---

**Original answer**

this appears to be a bug in SceneKit.

If that works for you a workaround would be to use an `ARSCNView`. It gives you access to all the SceneKit APIs, and it automatically draws the video feed as the scene's background.

Comment: Bug reappeared at iOS 11.3

Comment: I have encountered the same issue on iOS 11.4 on a 5S. However, I am using an AVPlayer rather than the AVCaptureDevice. Does anyone have a link to Apple's ticket to fix this issue?