# Changing ARSCNView background

Tags: ios, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit, arscnview

iOS 13.1.3 on iPad Pro

Seem like there is a a same problem on previous iOS versions.
[Using AVCaptureDevice as SCNScene background content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46173225/using-avcapturedevice-as-scnscene-background-content)

My app uses front cam to create AR face in iOS. At first tour, my app uses default SCNView with camera input. After first tour, I am setting ARSCNView background to a UIImage. After setting this I can't go back to previous state by setting `scnview.scene.background` to `nil` or `inputdevice`.

How can I take it back to previous state that shows camera input?
First, I set like below which is shown successfully.

```
sceneView.scene.background.contents = UIImage(named: "bruin.jpeg")
```

Then after 15 seconds, I set it with the code below but I get stable image not video preview layer.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, 
                                           for: .video, 
                                      position: .front)!
    self.sceneView.scene.background.contents = captureDevice
}
```

I get this error in output:

```
// SceneKit Error: Could not get pixel buffer (CVPixelBufferRef)
```

Comment: Show your code, please.

Comment: @ARGeo okey I added.